# The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. How do to solve this?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a big problem regarding the serialization of a Many to Many relationship with intermediate model in DRF: If the request method is get everything works perfectly. But as soon as i try to POST or PUT Data to the API I get the following Error:

> Internal Server Error: /api/ordering/ Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
>   line 54, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py",
>   line 116, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 495, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 455, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 492, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py",
>   line 21, in create
>       self.perform_create(serializer)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py",
>   line 26, in perform_create
>       serializer.save()   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py",
>   line 214, in save
>       self.instance = self.create(validated_data)   File "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py",
>   line 929, in create
>       raise_errors_on_nested_writes('create', self, validated_data)   File
>   "/home/neha/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py",
>   line 823, in raise_errors_on_nested_writes
>       class_name=serializer.**class**.**name**
>
> AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable
>   nested fields by default. Write an explicit `.create()` method for
>   serializer `ordering.serializers.CustOrderSerializer`, or set
>   `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

```
views.py
from ordering.models import CustOrder, Product, Price, City, Area

from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions

from .serializers import CustOrderSerializer, ProductSerializer, 
PriceSerializer, CitySerializer, AreaSerializer

class CustOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = CustOrder.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = CustOrderSerializer



class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]


    serializer_class = ProductSerializer


class PriceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Price.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = PriceSerializer

class CityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = City.objects.all()

    permissions_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = CitySerializer


class AreaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Area.objects.all()

    permisions_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = AreaSerializer 

    enter code here

 serializer.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from ordering.models import CustOrder, Area, City, Product, Price

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = '__all__'

queryset=Product.objects.all())
# class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#     class Meta:
#         model = Area
#         fields = '__all__'

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = '__all__'

class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Area
        fields = '__all__'


class CustOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    price = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='price',                                        queryset=Price.objects.all())
    # product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='product', queryset=Product.objects.all())
    area = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='address', queryset=Area.objects.all())
    city = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='city', queryset=City.objects.all())
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustOrder
        fields = '__all__' 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        products = validated_data.pop('product')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data) 
        for products in products:
            Product.objects.create(product=product, **products)
        return product

    # product = serializers.CharField(source="Product.product", read_only=True)
    # price = serializers.CharField(source="Price.price", read_only=True)
    # city = serializers.CharField(source="City.city", read_only=True)
    # area = serializers.CharField(source="Area.area", read_only=True)
    # price = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='price', queryset=Price.objects.all())
    # product = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='product', queryset=Product.objects.all())
    # area = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='address', queryset=Area.objects.all())
    # city = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='city', queryset=City.objects.all())
# def to_representation(self, instance):
#     response = super().to_representation(instance)
#     response['child'] = ProductSerializer(instance.product).data
#     return response  

    enter code here

model.py
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from phone_field import PhoneField
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import Sum
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cities"


class Area(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.address



class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True))
    # price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places = 5, default=0)
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return str(self.product)+ ":$" + str(self.price)
    # @property
    # def price(self):
    #     return "$%s" % self.price
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)

    # def __str__(self):
    #      return "%s" %  self.product_id
    # def natural_key(self):
    #     return self.product

    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name_plural = "Products"

class Price(models.Model):
    # product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='CustOrder', through_fields=('price', 'product'),)
    # price_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places = 5, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.price
        #  return str(self.product)+ ":$" +  str(self.price)



PRODUCT_CHOICES=(
     ('product_test_with_new_format','PRODUCT_TEST_WITH_NEW_FORMAT'),
     ('pulled chicken in pineapple relish','PULLED CHICKEN IN PINEAPPLE RELISH'),
     ('sundried sardines in mango relish', 'PULLED CHICKEN IN MANGO RELISH'),
     ('sundried sardines in mango relish','SUNDRIED SARDINES IN MANGO RELISH'),

)
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('male', 'MALE'),
    ('female', 'FEMALE'),
)
PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
    ('cod','COD'),
    ('card on delivery','CARD ON DELIVERY'),
    ('razor pay (netbanking)','RAZOR PAY (NET BANKING)'),
    ('razor pay (card)','RAZOR PAY (CARD)'),
    ('razor pay (wallet)','RAZOR PAY (WALLET)'),
    ('citrus','CITRUS'),
    ('paytm','PAYTM'),
)
CITY_CHOICES = (
    ('bangalore', 'BANGALORE'),
    ('hyderabad', 'HYDERABAD'),
    ('gurugram','GURUGRAM'),
    ('pune','PUNE'),
    ('chandigarh','CHANDIGARH'),
    ('mumbai','MUMBAI'),
)
# class ProductItem(models.Model):
# #     product = models.ManyToManyField(Price, through='CustOrder')
#     productitem = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='CustOrder', through_fields=('productitem', 'product'),)
#     def __str__(self):
#         return str(self.productitem)

class CustOrder(models.Model):
    Customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CustomerName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True, null= True, unique= True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = PhoneField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)
    landmark = models.PointField()
    #landmark = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the landmark", default='Enter landmark')
    houseno = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES,default='Boneless chicken')
    # product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='custorder_productid')

    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True,related_name='pricetag')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # price_id = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='pricetag')
    #price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default=48.9)
    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='RAZOR PAY')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Price.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
    def __str__(self):
         return self.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is related to the fact that you are returning a `Product` object instead of a `CustOrder` object ?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, you'll have to write your owm `.create()` method on the serializer, which takes care of creating on object off of the `validated_data` that is fed in.

By doing so, you can explicitely tell Django how to handle nested fields